# How to trigger Azure Ad B2c Custom policy api connector during refresh token generation

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

In our application architecture, we  are leveraging **Azure Active Directory B2C (Azure AD B2C)** to manage user authentication, specifically for sign-up and sign-in operations.

#### How the process works:

1. **User Authentication:** When a user tries to log in, they interact with the Azure AD B2C service.
2. **Token Generation:** Upon successful authentication, Azure AD B2C generates an `id_token`. This token essentially represents the authenticated user and contains claims about this user.
3. **Token Storage:** We're persisting this `id_token` in the browser's local storage to maintain the user's session and possibly for some other client-side operations.
4. **Custom Backend Interaction:** During the login and sign-up procedures, an API connector is triggered. This connector communicates with a custom backend API. The purpose of this interaction is to append some custom claims to the generated token. For instance, if a user has purchased a particular product, a claim denoting the `productId` is added to the token.

   The flow can be visualized as:

   ```
   User 
   |
   v
   Azure AD B2C 
   |
   v
   Custom Backend (to append custom claims)
   ```

#### The Challenge:

Consider a scenario where a new user registers and logs into our application. This new user then proceeds to make a purchase. The issue arises here because the token which was issued during the initial login still contains old data – it does not yet reflect the user's recent purchase. This means the `productId` claim, which should ideally indicate the newly purchased product, is absent or not updated in the token.

#### Solution Required:

To address this, we  want to generate a new token that contains the updated claims without prompting to user to login again

I am following these docs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/access-tokens

Comment: I think you need SSO importation because access-tokens is expire after some time like 1 hour. you need refresh token that generate access token and refresh token again and again no need login again and again only login first time. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to play with the Claim: refreshTokensValidFromDateTime seting it to the current time so token is invalidated and Refreshtoken Journey is fired in your custom policies.

You also can do this by calling the graph api directly from your Product API:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/{version}/users/{user_object_id}/invalidateAllRefreshTokens
```

An approach using Custom policies should be creating a UserJourney with something like this:

```
 <UserJourney Id="RedeemRefreshToken">
  <AssuranceLevel>LOA1</AssuranceLevel>
  <PreserveOriginalAssertion>false</PreserveOriginalAssertion>
  <OrchestrationSteps>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="VersionCheckRRT" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="REST-HasUpdatedProductClaims" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
        <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
          <Value>UpdatedProductClaim</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="RefreshTokenSetupExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="TP_RefreshTokenReadAndSetup" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
        <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
          <Value>UpdatedProductClaim</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="CheckRefreshTokenDateFromAadExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId-CheckRefreshTokenDate" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
  </OrchestrationSteps>
```

AAD Check RefreshToken Date:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId-CheckRefreshTokenDateAndReset">
      <DisplayName>Azure Active Directory</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.AzureActiveDirectoryProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" Required="true" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_UserProfileId" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_EmailVerified" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="oid" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="AssertRefreshTokenIssuedLaterThanValidFromDate" />
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromObjectID" />
      </OutputClaimsTransformations>
      <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

And a Claim Transformation to check or manipulate Token time:

```
 <ClaimsTransformation Id="AssertRefreshTokenIssuedLaterThanValidFromDate" TransformationMethod="AssertDateTimeIsGreaterThan">
    <InputClaims>
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="refreshTokenIssuedOnDateTime" TransformationClaimType="leftOperand" />
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="refreshTokensValidFromDateTime" TransformationClaimType="rightOperand" />
    </InputClaims>
    <InputParameters>
      <InputParameter Id="AssertIfEqualTo" DataType="boolean" Value="false" />
      <InputParameter Id="AssertIfRightOperandIsNotPresent" DataType="boolean" Value="true" />
    </InputParameters>
  </ClaimsTransformation>
```

This is just an approach that you can follow. Anyways i would think twice revoking tokens from user this way and would rethink your approach.

Tokens are used to exchange authentication handshake so both parties agree the client is able to talk to the server, investigating further probably will break how it is used OAuth2 and B2C.

Purchase a Product should be a simple API call and register the user has purchased that product, if you need it in the client side, what about use localCache?

Regards.